# What might cause Rails 5 to not set a parameter in build(), even if it's been filled in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am attempting to add a new field to a model in a Rails application. The field is a simple belongs_to relationship, which is set in the model, similar to other relationships on that same model.

I have added the field to the `modelname_params` method, and the create method of the controller does a `.build()` call with those params as the argument, all pretty standard.

The field shows up on the form, retrieves the correct values (it's a dropdown select), and if I place a `byebug` debugger just before the line where the code is saved, I can see that the value is in the params[] object, at the same level as all other fields.

And yet, when the save actually goes through, the new field is set to nil, rather than saving the data stored in params like I expect, without throwing an error or causing some other problem.

At this point, I am wondering if there's some Rails or Ruby mechanic I'm just not aware of, but I for the life of me can't seem to figure out how to get this field to save. To my eye, I am mirroring what the other fields do almost exactly, the only difference being the way the select field is rendered on the form. I have considered equalizing that as well but am running into a bit of an issue using the same Javascript-approach the other fields are using. Ideally I'd like the way I've set it up to work.

```
# create method 
def create
    @problem_report = current_project.problem_reports.build(problem_report_params)
*snip*
end
# strong params declaration
  def problem_report_params
    params.require(:problem_report).permit(
      :asset_code,
      :asset_id,
      :description,
      :reporter_name,
      :reporter_email,
      :priority,
      :building_id,
      :floor_id,
      :room_id,
      photos_attributes: [:id, :file, :_destroy]
    )
  end


# form

<div class="card card-default">
  <div class="card-body">
    <%= f.form_group :building_id, label: { text: "Building" } do %>
      <select id="buildings" name="problem_report[building_id]" class="select2-input" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="Select a building..."></select>
    <% end %> <!-- works -->
      <%= f.collection_select :asset_id, f.object.project.assets, :id, :name, { include_blank: true }, control_class: "select2-input", style: "width: 100%", data: { placeholder: "Select asset linked to this problem report..." } %> <!-- works as in the param gets in the right place, but isn't saved
    
    <%= f.form_group :floor_id, label: { text: "Floor" } do %>
      <select id="floors" name="problem_report[floor_id]" class="select2-input" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="Select a floor..."></select>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.form_group :room_id, label: { text: "Room" } do %>
      <select id="rooms" name="problem_report[room_id]" class="select2-input" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="Select a room..."></select>
    <% end %>

*snip* <!-- below, a bit of Javascript retrieves a resource as_json that has the details for floor, room and building, but not assets. That's why the approach is different for those -->

# Except, when I run this, the asset is not saved. I see it in params when I debug it, yet it is not saved, and I have no idea why not

# model
class ProblemReport < ApplicationRecord
*snip*
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :building, optional: true
  belongs_to :floor, optional: true
  belongs_to :room, optional: true
  belongs_to :asset, optional: true
*snip*
end

# currently, the inverse relationship doesn't exist sinceI'm only going the one way. Is that necessary?
```

The log output including `byebug` is rather long, I have stored in a Pastebin here:
https://pastebin.com/hbgDs9eH

If this is a duplicate, I might not be finding it because I don't know what I'm missing, if that makes sense. Linking me to a similar question that has a solution would therefore already be very much appreciated.

Comment: Show the relevant models (that show the inter-relationships). The log output on your screen should show you what your params hash looks like on the create call, and it will show the SQL command that it issued for your create. You should show that, too.

Comment: I have added this, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Is it just one field that is not saving? You mention "new field" and "this field" many times, but you never say exactly what the field is.

Comment: sorry about that,I thought it might be clearfrom the code. But the asset_id is the new field. The rest is saving as it should, but problem_reort.asset stays nil

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I do see that in your code comment now. I guess I was fixated on your description. The log shows that the params are not permitted. You could check to make sure you don't have any validation failures. Nothing else is jumping out at me at the moment.